# How can I create an alert dialog inside of a protractor e2e test?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I have some protractor tests that I run and record in a video log. I would like to be able to create a pop-up dialog to indicate during the video which test is currently being run. 
I want to display something within the browser that originates from the protractor test code (not from within the application being tested).
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

browser.executeScript( 'alert("This will show an alert. How you get rid of it is up to you")');